# Cordova: Modifying *-Info.plist from plugin.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, info.plist

I'm building a plugin to use star printers from an iOS device, with their [SDK](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx) and everything is working fine except that `config-file` command to modify the info.plist file is not working properly. Inside my **plugin.xml** I have:

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="Supported external accessory protocols">
  <array>
    <key>item 0</key>
    <string>jp.star-m.starpro</string>
  </array>
</config-file>
```

With that I should get a `Supported external accessory protocols` array with 1 item called `item 0`, type `String` and value `jp.star-m.starpro` but instead I'm getting an array with two items as if I would have done:

```
<array>
    <key>item 0</key>
    <string>item 0</string>
    <key>item 1</key>
    <string>jp.star-m.starpro</string>
</array>
```

What I need:
[image: one item]

---

What I get:
[image: two items]

---

Related questions:

I implemented the `config-file` by reading from this questions.

1. [Add entry to iOS .plist file via Cordova config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769111/add-entry-to-ios-plist-file-via-cordova-config-xml)
2. [Two cordova plugins modifying “*-Info.plist” CFBundleURLTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886891/two-cordova-plugins-modifying-info-plist-cfbundleurltypes)

Comment: Could try out this config: <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="Supported external accessory protocols">
    <array>
        <dict>
          <key>item 0</key>
          <array>
            <string>jp.star-m.starpro</string>            
          </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</config-file>

Comment: Hi @Gandhi, that would give me an string inside an array, inside a dictionary all keyed with item 0. I tried it anyhow, but it didn't work.

Comment: How about using this plugin which simplifies your task - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config

Comment: Hi @Gandhi, that would probably work, anyhow I already found out how to write the `config-file`, thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad it worked but sad I missed out on the bounty. Was real close:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further testing and research, I found out how to write the `config-file` to work properly. Here is the xml

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols">
    <array>
        <string>jp.star-m.starpro</string>
    </array>
</config-file>
```

Here, I changed the parent name from `Supported external accessory protocols` to `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols`and remove the `<key>` tag and now works as expected.

Comment: Hey Jose, have you shared your plugin somewhere ? Github maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [custom config plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) which should simply your task. This helps in manipulating *-info.plist file the way you intend to.

Comment: That looks like a useful plugin for editing the info.plist from a cordova app, but (not sure if i missed it) how would I use this from a plugin? Because that is what I need.

Comment: @Jose its a plugin by itself used to manipulate the .plist file. Not sure whether i understood you question properly

Comment: What I need to do is modify the .plist file from a plugin, so I don't know how would I use this plugin from another plugin (the one I'm building)

Comment: @Jose if the only purpose of your custom plugin is jus to update .plist file, then u can use this readymade plugin instead of yours. If your custom plugin does anything more, then leave the .plist file updation to this plugin.But if u wanna use this inside your plugin, suggest you to look at file transfer plugin which uses file plugin as its dependent plugin. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Jose Thanks Jose. you made my day. Cheers