# Add fields to info.plist in cordova ios app

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, plugins

I need to create custom plugin that will add entries to info.plist for cordova/angular4 iOS application. (In this case exit application if home button pressed)

I need to add row:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

Here is the content of plugin I wrote (which may be not correct, because I couldn't test it).

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" platform="ios" parent="UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend">
<array>
  <boolean><true/></boolean>
</array>
</config-file>
```

What is needed to 'import' this plugin to config.xml and so that every time I do `cordova build ios` plist file will have entries I need?

I've read this posts and I didn't understood how it's done.

[Add entry to iOS .plist file via Cordova config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769111/add-entry-to-ios-plist-file-via-cordova-config-xml)

[Cordova: Modifying *-Info.plist from plugin.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285458/cordova-modifying-info-plist-from-plugin-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After couple of hours of search and few attempts it was actually enough to just add:

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist"parent="UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend">
    <true/>
</config-file>
```

(which in my case prevents application from running in the background)

**right into** `config.xml` and nest it inside `<platform name="ios">` tag as if it was your plugin. And this setting will be added to `*-info.plist` during `cordova build ios` **without any need to manually install** your custom plugin.

**Hint:** I was firstly mistaken that instead of `*` in `target="*-Info.plist"` there has to be your app's title, but as it happens there actually has to be a `*` symbol and cordova itself will figure out the name of info.plist for you application.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this configuration in plugin.xml.

Inside the ios platform add below lines of code:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend">
      <true/>
    </config-file>
 </platform>
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: I have tried it and few variations already, nothing happens in .plist. Should I give just a name of .plist file as target, or relative path?

Comment: Hope you are installing the plugin through command line using `cordova plugin add <path>`

Comment: I'm receiving Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.pmi.ca223

Comment: How does config know that plugin should be run when building ios platform app?

Comment: I guess you are following standard procedure.
When you install the plugin through command line in your Cordova project it will write the configuration values in the platform level .plist file.

Comment: If you created a custom plugin in your local then follow this link to install  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345035/how-to-add-a-local-cordova-plugin-with-ionic

Comment: I don't use Ionic, or it is irrelevant in this situation? And how to make sure plugin is added to config every time build is done?

Comment: No not required. You can manually add a key in .plist file from Xcode. Build will not remove the key from plist.